# Fixed chatboxes inside a container

Tags: html, css

[image]

Inside the div `chatbox-container` I have two chatboxes that are set to `float: right` with `margin-right: 15px`.

```
.chatbox-container {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

The problem is that I can't select/click on things that are directly beneath the `chatbox-container`. For example if the `1,293 views` was a button, I wouldn't be able to click on it unless the chatboxes were beneath that text, nor could I right click directly on the 'upload' image beneath it to get the link (for example)

How can I be able to click on things beneath the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the `.chatbox-container` has `width:100%`. Remove the `left:0` from your CSS, since this is what making your div to have width equal to 100%.

```
.chatbox-container {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah it was the `left: 0`!

Comment: I had exactly the same issue on my chat implementation!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
pointer-events: none;
```

is the CSS code to prevent clicking is enabled in DIVs.

After that use

```
pointer-events: auto;
```

to restore the pointer events in the children of the container, so that you are still able to select the chatbox.

Hope this helps